# Installing Python on Apache

Tags: python, apache, xampp, lampp

Since self-explaining text didnt work, I will make it 50 times shorter. I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 with XAMPP and other stuff in /opt/lampp/
How to add python **there**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu, you can install mod_wsgi like this :

```
$> apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Use the python version you're more confortable with AND that will be compatible with the libs you're using :)

Answer (score 1):

I realize that you already have an installed version of apache, but the Apache2 deb packages are quite complete on Ubuntu. If you just want to get up and running, you could just

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-python
```

and that should pull in all of your dependencies. You would need to either shutdown the /opt installed apache, or just set the deb-packaged Apache to Listen 8080 (or some such). the conf files are in /etc/apache2.

Also, if you want to see what else is available form the repos, (everything you have installed is in there):

```
sudo apt-cache search apache2
```

Good luck!
speeves

Comment: Using mod_python is not recommended these days as the project is no longer developed or supported.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, Graham! I see your post here: http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/06/modpython-project-is-now-officially.html . I see that the libapache2-mod-python package is still being maintained in Debian unstable, which will feed into Ubuntu, so I am interested to see/hear when they will deprecate the package.

Comment: When Apache 2.4 is released they will not have much choice as mod_python likely may need a bit of work to compile on it. Although they maintain a few patches to allow mod_python to build on latest Apache 2.2.X, pulled from unreleased mod_python code in its source repo, there will be no source of patches to get it working with Apache 2.4.